# What is 'base space' and relationship with scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

I have a very stupid and simple question, which I do not have a clear idea on. One [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.socnet.2010.02.001) (Third Paragraph of `Page-199`) that I read said,

> "As a basic relationship in linear algebra states,
> the scalar product of vectors $x$ and $y$ in a base space of $A$ is
> $xAy$."

The snapshot of corresponding page.
[image]

What does the 'base space' specifically represent? Is there any other term that indicates the same concept? What is the difference between ordinary scalar or inner product $xy$ and $xAy$? What role base space A does play? What are the impacts by converting $xy$ into $xAy$? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> What does the 'base space' specifically represent?

In this case, we're talking about a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$, equipped with some bilinear form $V\times V\to F$. One can say that the set $V$ is the base space for the bilinear form. You can also call it the "underlying space."

Then, when generating a geometric(/Clifford) algebra using $V$ and this bilinear form, you still can refer to $V$ as the "base" for the algebra since it is the key thing you need to generate the algebra.

$V$ is important it is usually used to model geometric things very directly, whereas elements of the Clifford algebra are interpreted as operating on the things in the underlying space. For example *rotors* are elements of the algebra that act on an image of $V$ in the Clifford algebra, modeling rotation in $V$.

> What is the difference between ordinary scalar or inner product $xy$ and $xAy$?

Really, there are a couple of things to get your head around here. The first one is the idea of a bilinear form $B:V\times V\to F$. This is an abstract thing with [particular properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form).

If you *fix a basis of $V$* then you can express a bilinear form as $B(x,y)=x^\top Ay$ where $x,y$ are column vectors and $A$ is a matrix, and the second half of the equality is matrix multiplication. One special case of this is when $A$ is the identity matrix, and then you have the regular inner product.

It's important to realize that $A$ *depends on the basis you chose*.  $A$ is not unique to $B$, $A$ is unique with respect to $B$ *and the basis.* If you transform from one basis to another using a matrix $X$, then $A$ changes to $X^\top A X$. Under some circumstances, you may be able to take a matrix $A$ and find a change of basis so that $X^\top AX=I_n$ in the new basis, and then your new basis makes your bilinear form look like the dot product.

Another thing to realize is that if $B$ is symmetric (that is, $B(x,y)=B(y,x)$ for all $x,y$) then $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

I am not really sure if you actually mean $xAy$, since normally we like to interpret this as matrix multiplication $x^\top Ay$. However, it is totally understandable why one might write $xBy$ instead of $B(x,y)$ for aesthetic reasons.

P.S.: I could not access the article you're talking about.